# understanding zend 2 routing

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend MVC. Below is a snippet of code in the module.config.php file.Here I want to understand how the 'controller' and the 'action' variables are picked up by the Zend. Are these two special names that always direct to the respective controllers and actions? I feel that it is not so, as the 'postId' is an arbitrary variable name. So the question is just how does the framework know how to process these two variables. Where are they passed to? I hope I made the question clear.

[code]

```
'options' => array(
'route'    => '/blog/post[/:postId]',
'defaults' => array(
'controller'    => 'blog',
'action'        => 'post',
'postId'            => '1'
 )
```

[/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the special names. ZF uses this parameters to determine which controller and action to dispatch the request to.

After a route is matched against one of your configured patterns the framework will build a `RouteMatch` object and set all the parameters on it (in this case `controller`, `action` and `postId`). The RouteMatch object is then set on the `MvcEvent` which is available throughout the application.

For example you can access the available params in you controller action:

```
public function myAction()
{
    var_dump($this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('postId'));

    // Or much shorter use the `Params` controller plugin
    var_dump($this->params('postId'));
}
```

You could also create "magic" routes which has placeholders for the controller and action params. i.e.

```
'options' => array(
    'route'    => '/:controller/:action[/:postId]',
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller'    => 'blog',
        'action'        => 'post',
        'postId'            => '1'
     )
 )
```

If you go to /blog/list now, you request will be dispatched to the list action in the blog controller.